# Why won't my method display the value unless I add an XML placeholder in my strings.XML? Android Development

Tags: java, android, xml, string

I've been studying android development through Udacity for the past couple of months and I ran into a strange issue that wasn't explained very well and hopefully I can get some insight.  Sorry I don't know all of the Java verbiage so bear with me.

I ran into a problem when I was adding all of my strings to the strings.XML file.  I was working on a setup for supporting different languages.  I went over some of the documentation for xliff and that part is used to identify parts of the string you don't want translated.  The %s (placeholder?) part is what I have no experience with and it seems to change the way I write my java code.

This is my code for an app I made for this question.

**Here is my strings.xml I commented out the xliff:g that changes the behavior of my java code, which I will explain later**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<string name="app_name">Test Application</string>

<!--store customer name is string here to be used later-->
    <string name="order_summary_name">customer name is: <!--<xliff:g id="name" example="Amy">%s</xliff:g>--></string>
</resources>
```

**Activity_Main.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.testapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test Display Customer Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/customer_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_name_here"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/display_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Text"
        android:onClick="submitText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
package com.example.android.testapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    //Display Message Method

    private void displayMessage(String message) {
        TextView displayTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_name_here);
        displayTextView.setText(message);
    }

    //Submit Text Method

    public void submitText (View view) {
        EditText editViewCustomerName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.customer_name);
        String customerName = editViewCustomerName.getText().toString();

        String customMessage = createOrderSummary(customerName);
        displayMessage(customMessage);
    }

    //Create order summary that only has the customer name

    private String createOrderSummary(String addCustomerName) {
        String orderMessage = getString(R.string.order_summary_name, addCustomerName);
        return orderMessage;
    }
}
```

This is the string that I am working with that displays the customer's name on my phone when I click Show Text.  This is what the instructor had us write out, but didn't explain that you can separate the R.id string with a comma and then call the addCustomerName to display the name you entered in.

**Instructors code change that is different from mine**

```
String orderMessage = getString(R.string.order_summary_name, addCustomerName);
```

**This is the way I had it before and it worked. This is my code piece**

```
String orderMessage = getString(R.string.order_summary_name) + addCustomerName;
```

However this is where I get really confused.  If I comment out my xliff in my Strings.XML file (like I already have it) I cannot use the instructors code with separating the string and the addCustomerName with a comma and keeping it within the parenthesis.  I have to concatenate it like I have above.

I have searched around and since I am new to this I don't know what to look for.  The only thing I found out that is removing the %s (which is an XML placeholder?) it breaks using the instructors code.  However when I put it back in it works??

If anybody can explain this it would be greatly appreciated.  I've been stumped on this for days.

Here are some screen shots of what it looks like on my device when using the instructors code.

**Removed %s from my xliff on Strings.XML**

[Not displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAUsX.png)

**Added %s back into the xliff on Strings.XML**

[Now it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLHuq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get familiar with http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

If you have placeholders in your string, then getString will replace them given the values in the 2nd, 3rd,... arguments to getString. On the other hand, even if you give an argument, it doesn't know where to put it if there's no placeholder in the string.

The format is explained here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

As for your questions in the comments:

The number of placeholders in the "format string" (which is R.string.order_summary_name) and the number of arguments to getString have to match (arguments have to be number of placeholders+1, 'cause obviously the 1st argument is the format string itself). If there are less placeholders, then it's probably not a problem, you just won't see the last arguments you pass rendered in the string, but if there are more placeholders than arguments, then it will probably even throw an exception.

Comment: I've read through that and how would I do the string formatting without the xliff:g?  I'm still not clear on what the definitions of the actual syntax for placeholders are?  I run into %s, $, %b, %d, but I don't know the definitions are?  Is there documentation on what and how to use it properly?

Comment: Thanks for that information.  However I am still lost on why it changes the format to where you can put the two arguments within the () of the getString(R.id, second argument).

Comment: I see.  Thanks for that information.  Adding in a second string %s does throw an exception tied to the Strings.XML.  Reading the documentation doesn't seem very clear yet and I didn't know I could change the way I write my java code, since I usually hard code the formatting of the strings.